# Sd Image not booting

Tags: sd-card, retropie

I recently purchased a new Rpi and have been having problems with SD card images. I have only a 4gb sd lying around and since my plan was to use it for retropie I thought it would be fine.

I went through all the steps of mounting the img to the sd card using win32diskimager and the pi did not boot. I then read about a problem with the older os versious and the newer hynix chips, which I have.
So I downloaded noobs and installed raspian without any problems. Went to install retropie from the commandline and I did not have enough space. So I tried to burn the raspian img to the card and it did not work.

I'm assuming it is a problem with my computer mounting the img files on the Sd card, has anyone else experienced this or does anyone have a solution?

My pi turns on and the green light flickers but there is nothing showing up on the screen.

Comment: You haven't told us HOW you tried to program the card, so we can't help.

Comment: Recommended memory is 8 GB. Please use that!

Answer (score 1):

Retropie image does not necessarily fit on 4GB SD card, please, read comments below download section on their site. Your best bet would be to go and get an 8GB card that are dirt cheap these days.

Otherwise you may install Raspbian using your favourite method (NOOBS ?) and then download and use [RetroPie Setup Script](http://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/07/22/retropie-setup-an-initialization-script-for-retroarch-on-the-raspberry-pi/), that will download and setup all the software if you have enough space, or not if you don't and then you have to buy 8GB card anyway.

Comment: Got my hands on an 8gb sd card and tried the img again but it did not work. Just used noobs and installed retropie from the script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome! there's no problem that cannot be solved by double-sized SD card =)